# VLC for iOS not compiling with xcode 5, iOS 7 error gcrypt

Tags: ios, tags, vlc

I downloaded the latest git branch (master) of the VLC for iOS but I got the following compilation error, anyone can help? Thanks :)

```
libtool: compile: unable to infer tagged configuration
libtool: compile: specify a tag with `--tag'
make[2]: *** [mpih-add1-asm.lo] Error 1
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [.gcrypt] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was resolved tonight by updating patch 0017 iOS.git's /patches.

Apply it to the VLC checkout in ImportedSources and make sure remove any remnants of libgcrypt in the VLC's contrib sub folder.
Alternatively, just remove the VLC folder all together.

In either case, re-run the build script and see it succeeding.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

This is a libcrypt lib issue.  There are few buggy versions of libcrypt which creates the issue . if you Update the version this gets fixed

For me lower versions(1.4.X) gave the error.

```
mpih-add1-asm.S:47:suffix or operands invalid for `push'
```

mpih-add1-asm.S:48:suffix or operands invalid for `push'
mpih-add1-asm.S:78:suffix or operands invalid for`jmp'
mpih-add1-asm.S:113:suffix or operands invalid for `pop'
mpih-add1-asm.S:114:suffix or operands invalid for`pop'
make[1]: *** [mpih-add1-asm.lo] Error 1
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1

The libcrypt 1.5.0 worked -
 ftp://ftp.gnupg.org/gcrypt/libgcrypt/libgcrypt-1.5.0.tar.gz